Flutter awesome_notifications_fcm ios action button not showing
Hi I am using awesome_notifications_fcm package for showing firebase notification
so i send notification from backend using node.js
i want to show notification with action button, its working for android devices but ios just showing notification only
This is flutter code

class NotificationController with ChangeNotifier {
  static final NotificationController _instance =
      NotificationController._internal();

  factory NotificationController() => _instance;

  NotificationController._internal();

  /// INITIALIZATION

  static Future<void> initializeRemoteNotifications() async {
    final _permission = await AwesomeNotifications()
        .requestPermissionToSendNotifications(permissions: [
      NotificationPermission.Light,
      NotificationPermission.Vibration,
      NotificationPermission.Alert
    ]);
    if (_permission) {
      await AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
        null,
        [
          NotificationChannel(
            channelKey: 'alerts',
            channelName: 'Alerts',
            channelDescription: 'Alerts',
            importance: NotificationImportance.High,
            channelShowBadge: true,
            enableLights: true,
            playSound: true,
            criticalAlerts: true,
            enableVibration: true,
          ),
        ],
      );
      await AwesomeNotificationsFcm().initialize(
        onFcmSilentDataHandle: onSilentDataHandle,
        onFcmTokenHandle: onFcmTokenHandle,
        onNativeTokenHandle: onNativeTokenHandle,
        licenseKeys: Constants.awesomeNotificationLicenceKeys,
        debug: false,
      );
      await initializeIsolateReceivePort();
    } else {
      await openAppSettings();
    }
  }

  static Future<void> initializeNotificationListeners() async {
    // Only after at least the action method is set,
    //the notification events are delivered
    await AwesomeNotifications().setListeners(
      onActionReceivedMethod: onActionReceivedMethod,
      onNotificationCreatedMethod: onNotificationCreatedMethod,
      onNotificationDisplayedMethod: onNotificationDisplayedMethod,
      onDismissActionReceivedMethod: onDismissActionReceivedMethod,
    );
  }

  static Future<void> getInitialNotificationAction() async {
    final ReceivedAction? receivedAction = await AwesomeNotifications()
        .getInitialNotificationAction(removeFromActionEvents: false);
    if (receivedAction == null) return;
    // TODO: Handle Initial Notification Action
  }

  static ReceivePort? receivePort;

  static Future<void> initializeIsolateReceivePort() async {
    receivePort = ReceivePort('Notification action port in main isolate')
      ..listen(
          (silentData) => onActionReceivedImplementationMethod(silentData));

    IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
        receivePort!.sendPort, 'notification_action_port');
  }

  /// NOTIFICATION METHODS

  /// Use this method to detect when a new notification or a schedule is created
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future<void> onNotificationCreatedMethod(
      ReceivedNotification receivedNotification) async {}

  /// Use this method to detect every time that a new notification is displayed
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future<void> onNotificationDisplayedMethod(
      ReceivedNotification receivedNotification) async {}

  /// Use this method to detect if the user dismissed a notification
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future<void> onDismissActionReceivedMethod(
      ReceivedAction receivedAction) async {}

  /// Use this method to detect when the user taps on a notification
  ///  or action button
  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  static Future<void> onActionReceivedMethod(
      ReceivedAction receivedAction) async {
    if (receivedAction.buttonKeyPressed.isEmpty) {
      final String? route = receivedAction.payload?['route'];
      if (route == null) return;
      navigate(route);
    }

    if (receivedAction.actionType == ActionType.SilentAction ||
        receivedAction.actionType == ActionType.SilentBackgroundAction) {
      // For background actions, you must hold the execution until the end
      await executeLongTaskInBackground(receivedAction);
      return;
    } else {
      if (receivePort == null) {
        // onActionReceivedMethod was called inside a parallel dart isolate.
        final SendPort? sendPort =
            IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('notification_action_port');

        if (sendPort != null) {
          // Redirecting the execution to main isolate process (this process is
          // only necessary when you need to redirect the user to a new page or
          // use a valid context)
          sendPort.send(receivedAction);
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    return onActionReceivedImplementationMethod(receivedAction);
  }

  static void navigate(String route) {
    Get.key.currentState?.pushNamed(route);
  }

  static Future<void> onActionReceivedImplementationMethod(
      ReceivedAction receivedAction) async {
    AwesomeNotifications().resetGlobalBadge();

    // TODO: Handle Action button
  }

  /// REMOTE NOTIFICATION METHODS

  /// Use this method to execute on background when a silent data arrives
  /// (even while terminated)
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future<void> onSilentDataHandle(FcmSilentData silentData) async {
    print('Silent Data: $silentData');
    // TODO: Handle Silent Data
  }

  /// Use this method to detect when a new fcm token is received
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future<void> onFcmTokenHandle(String fcmToken) async {
    final FcmTokenUsecase fcmTokenUsecase = Get.find();

    await fcmTokenUsecase.updateFcmToken(fcmToken);
  }

  /// Use this method to detect when a new native token is received
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future<void> onNativeTokenHandle(String token) async {}

  /// Silent Background notification action
  static Future<void> executeLongTaskInBackground(
      ReceivedAction receivedAction) async {
    // TODO: Execute Background Task
  }

  /// Get FCM TOKEN
  Future<String> getFCMToken() async {
    if (await AwesomeNotificationsFcm().isFirebaseAvailable) {
      try {
        final token = await AwesomeNotificationsFcm().requestFirebaseAppToken();

        print('Fcm Token: $token');
        log("Fcm Token: $token");
        return token;
      } catch (exception) {
        debugPrint('$exception');
      }
    } else {
      debugPrint('Firebase is not available on this project');
    }
    return '';
  }

this flutter code don't need to write create notification method, its automatically showing its fine
Node.js code
const payload = {
                token: record.token,
                notification: {
                    title: record.title,
                    body: record.body,
                },
                data: {
                    role: record?.type ?? '', 
                    topic: record?.action ?? '', 
                    sub_topic: record?.title ?? '', 
                    "actionButtons.0.key": "REDIRECT",
                    "actionButtons.0.label": "Redirect",
                    "actionButtons.0.autoDismissible": "true",
                }
            };
            console.log('Sending payload:', payload);

            const response = await admin.messaging().send(payload);


i can control the notification content and action button or image url anything will send from backend and its automatically change based on json
